# Supposedly same integral gives different results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I need to compute the number $ \sigma_U $ for every open bounded subset of $ n $-dimensional Euclidean space defined as

$$ \sigma_U=\iint_Ud(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy $$

How can I compute this?

For $ n=1 $, at first I thought that, if we define `reg` as a valid region, for example, `reg = RegionUnion[Interval[{-3,-1}], Interval[{1,3}]]`, then

```
Integrate[Abs[x-y],{x,y} ∈ RegionProduct[reg,reg]]
```

and

```
Integrate[Integrate[Abs[x-y], {x} ∈ reg], {y} ∈ reg]
```

would result in the same value, but they don't, so, which is it?

I believe it is the latter, but I thought that the first one results in the same value. Thanks.

Comment: In what sense is the result of the second integral problematic? Also, you haven't specify `reg`, yet.

Comment: Does `Integrate[
 Integrate[Abs[x - y], {x} ∈ reg, 
  Assumptions -> {y} ∈ reg], {y} ∈ reg]` give the same answer as `Integrate[Abs[x-y],{x,y} ∈ RegionProduct[reg,reg]]`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `reg` could be, for example, `RegionUnion[Interval[{-3,-1}],Interval[{1,3}]]`, which gives different answers, one says its $24$, and the other one $112/3$.

Comment: @ChipHurst Check the previous comment. It does give different results for the given example.

Comment: Please write a title that actually applies to your specific problem and which will help others find it and its associated answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just some observations that take up too much room for a comment.

Integrate and NIntegrate give two different answers. Since your integral evaluates to a number, it is always easy to do a spot check on the symbolics side of the house:

```
Integrate[Abs[x-y],{x,y} ∈ RegionProduct[reg,reg]]
 (* 24 *)

NIntegrate[Abs[x-y],{x,y} ∈ RegionProduct[reg,reg]]
 (* 37.3333 = N[112/3] *)
```

Your second integral didn't evaluate cleanly for me until a let MMA know `y` was a real number for the inner integral.

```
 Assuming[y∈Reals,Integrate[Integrate[Abs[x - y],{x}∈reg],{y}∈reg]]
 (*  112/3 *)
```

The plot of the region `rp=RegionProduct[reg,reg]` is a little odd, although the area computation comes out right. Couldn't figure out if the clipped corners are an artifact or not. Doesn't seem like enough area to make up the difference between 24 and 37.333, but suggests something odd is going on behind the curtain.

```
 Area[rp]
 (* 16 *)
 Region[rp, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Both integrals do fine if the function is just `1`.

```
 Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ rp]
 Integrate[Integrate[Abs[x - y],{x}∈reg],{y}∈reg]
  (* 16 *)
```

Comment: I don't get those clippings using `RegionPlot[RegionProduct[reg,reg]]`, but yes, something odd is happening, I also tried using `Norm` instead of `Abs`, but I get the same results.

Comment: II am using v11.3.0.0, just for reference.

Comment: My version is 10.0.0.0